# Page controls lose style after page reload

Tags: angular, sass, kendo-ui

I have a single page application that converts DOM html into Kendo controls on the page on the fly and shows them in the browser.  I have a SASS stylesheet that styles all control, part of it is as below.  All controls have .company-container class and the below styles them by putting a border around the control when controls are not in the Edit mode and not focused.  This and other parts of this style file work fine till I hit Refresh to reload the page.  As soon as I reload the page in Chrome, the border around the control is lost, even though I clearly see that the html structure is there.  The other parts of the stylesheet are loading fine after the page reload, so I'm sure this is not a style cache issue.  I was wondering if you have seems an issue like this before.

A section of the .scss file that is being used:

```
.company-container > span span {
       outline-color: $color-brand;
       outline-width: $border-light;
       outline-style: solid;
       outline-offset: $border-light;
   }
```

Comment: hi, intersting, perhaps check in dev tools in the browser if the rule is getting applied? perhaps it's overridden by another rule

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed sometimes Kendo styling will end up overriding some of my stylesheets. First thing I'd do is add !important to your styles that are getting overridden to see if that is the issue.

Next, you may want to check that your .scss file is being called after your kendo (and all other) stylesheets.

You may also want to check in the inspector and see if element in question specificity is pointing to another stylesheet for precedence. (Check out W3's article on specificity for more info https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp )